# Python 2.7 installation failed: The installer could not install the software

Tags: macos, python-2.7, installation

I bought a new macbook pro (2016) recently and I am trying to install python 2.7, since all of my old python scripts are written in 2.7. However, I get the following error when trying to install:

[image]

I have googled https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/issues/291
and have come across some potential reasons involving "the root." Any thoughts on how I can install python on my MacBook Pro? Thanks!

Comment: What OS version is installed/running on the MacBook Pro? From what I understand, *all* Macs come with some standard Python versions pre-installed by Apple, usually Python 2.6 and 2.7 since they are required for the Mac Operating System itself to run. That may not be what's causing that error message, but likely there may be a conflict with installing a Python version over the same version that already exists in the core system. See [Using Python on a Macintosh](https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html#getting-and-installing-macpython)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `terminal` to install python. Instructions can be found in this link:
https://zaiste.net/posts/installing_python_27_on_osx_with_homebrew/

Two steps:
1) `brew update`
2)`brew install python`